# Tool for drawing automata and syntax trees

Tags: windows, finite-automata, diagramming

I am searching for a free tool(s) to create visually appealing diagrams of finite automata and syntax trees.
Note: I really just want to draw diagrams. I do not have to create a model or do something fancy with it.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**:
I might add, that I am creating documentation in Latex and therefore I am also open to tex-based diagramming solutions.

Comment: Moved to software recommendations SE: [Tool for drawing parse trees](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/74012/903)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does Graphviz meet your needs: creates diagrams from text
example: 
http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.html