# Tool for drawing parse trees?

Tags: graphviz, context-free-grammar, parse-tree

Does anyone have a good tool for drawing parse trees arising from a context-free grammar? There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113867/tool-for-drawing-automata-and-syntax-trees), but it dealt specifically with finite automata instead of parse trees. I've been using graphviz, but it's kind of annoying to have to label each node individually etc.

Comment: Are you trying to visualize the parse tree of a parser's output, or the parser itself?

Comment: @Flynn1179: the output. But I don't want to write a parser, I want something that is like paint, i.e. I just draw some trees.

Comment: Moved to software recommendations SE: [Tool for drawing parse trees](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/74012/903)

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/.

Example:

[image]

Input was:

```
[ROOT
  [S
    [S
      [NP [PRP It]]
      [VP [VBZ is]
        [NP
          [QP [RB nearly] [DT half] [JJ past] [CD five]]]]]
    [, ,]
    [S
      [NP [PRP we]]
      [VP [MD can] [RB not]
        [VP [VB reach]
          [NP [NN town]]
          [PP [IN before]
            [NP [NN dark]]]]]]
    [, ,]
    [S
      [NP [PRP we]]
      [VP [MD will]
        [VP [VB miss]
          [NP [NN dinner]]]]]
    [. .]]]
```

Also works if the string has no line breaks, e.g.:

```
[S [NP [DT The] [NN man]] [VP [VBZ is] [VP [VBG running] [PP [IN on] [NP [DT the] [NN mountain]]]]] [. .]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a well-written context-free grammar(CFG) then you can draw the tree diagram simply by using nltk library.

```
import nltk
#defining Contex Free Grammar
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
  S  -> NP VP
  NP -> Det Nom | PropN
  Nom -> Adj Nom | N
  VP -> V Adj | V NP | V S | V NP PP
  PP -> P NP
  PropN -> 'Buster' | 'Chatterer' | 'Joe'
  Det -> 'the' | 'a'
  N -> 'bear' | 'squirrel' | 'tree' | 'fish' | 'log'
  Adj  -> 'angry' | 'frightened' |  'little' | 'tall'
  V ->  'chased'  | 'saw' | 'said' | 'thought' | 'was' | 'put'
  P -> 'on'
  """)

sentence = 'the angry bear chased the frightened little squirrel'.split()
def parse(sent):
    #Returns nltk.Tree.Tree format output
    a = []  
    parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)
    for tree in parser.parse(sent):
        a.append(tree)
    return(a[0]) 

#Gives output as structured tree   
print(parse(sentence))

#Gives tree diagrem in tkinter window
parse(sentence).draw()
```

**Structured tree output**

[image]

**Tree Diagram in Tkinter Window**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://brenocon.com/parseviz/:

Input:

```
(S (NP (DT The) (NN man)) (VP (VBZ is) (VP (VBG running) (PP (IN on) (NP (DT the) (NN mountain))))) (. .))
```

Output:

[image]